# Disallow character if not prefixed with another character using regex

Tags: regex, ruby

I have incorporated the following regular expression into my code:

```
.gsub(/(^|[^*])(\*\*)([^*]+)(\*\*)($|[^*])/m, '\1*\3*\5') # bold
```

The issue I'm facing is that the \3 block (defined as `[^*]+`) doesn't currently permit asterisks `*` within the text.

My objective is to modify the regular expression in such a way that it allows asterisks only if they are preceded by an escape character `\`. What is the appropriate approach to achieve this modification?

Examples: `**hello \* world**` I want it to output `*hello \* world*`

But I got the text with no change with the current regex.

Comment: Please add example input and desired output.

Comment: Related: *[Regex for quoted string with escaping quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/249791)*.

Comment: If you are dealing with Markdown, it's best to use a parser. Potential duplicates: *[Ruby: how to generate HTML from Markdown like GitHub's or BitBucket's?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48885559)*, *[Better ruby markdown interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373002)*.

Comment: I am trying to do another thing with the markdown

Comment: @OmarFareed can you explain what other thing you are doing and why a Markdown parser doesn't help?

Comment: I am converting from markdown syntax to whatsapp syntax (in bold and italic, etc)

Comment: @OmarFareed converters like [Kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/) are quite versatile in that regard. They work in two steps: 1) importing the input format (markdown) into some internal structure, and 2) exporting the internal structure into the output format (e.g HTML/LaTeX/PDF/plain text). You could extend such converter by implementing a custom Whatsapp exporter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these situations, you can use an unrolled `[^*\\]*(?:\\.[^*\\]*)*`:

```rb
.gsub(/(^|[^*])(\*\*)([^*\\]*(?:\\.[^*\\]*)*)(\*\*)($|[^*])/m, '\1*\3*\5') # bold
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gDCCI6/2). Which can be further optimized to

```rb
.gsub(/(?<!\*)\*\*([^*\\]*(?:\\.[^*\\]*)*)\*\*(?!\*)/m, '*\1*')
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gDCCI6/4)

*Details*:

- `(?<!\*)` - a position that is not immediately preceded with a `*`
- `\*\*` - a `**` string
- `([^*\\]*(?:\\.[^*\\]*)*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `\` and `*` and then zero or more sequences of a `\` char followed by any other char and then zero or more characters other than `*` and `\`
- `\*\*` - a `**` string
- `(?!\*)` -  a position that is not immediately followed with a `*`

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/sL5eh3):

```rb
text = '**hello \* world**'
puts text.gsub(/(?<!\*)\*\*([^*\\]*(?:\\.[^*\\]*)*)\*\*(?!\*)/m, '*\1*') 
# => *hello \* world*
```

Comment: i didn't get the expected output with this regex,
i added an example if the question was not clear.

Comment: Also, consider `gsub(/(?<!\*)((?:\*\*)*)\*\*([^*\\]*(?:\\.[^*\\]*)*)\*\*((?:\*\*)*)(?!\*)/, '\1*\2*\3')` for more complex scenarios. The `\n`s in the demo are just for line-by-line demo.

Comment: and thanks for the demo, I will have a look at it

Comment: @OmarFareed That does exactly what you asked for. See https://regex101.com/r/gDCCI6/6. I also added a Ruby demo.

Comment: I've confirmed that the solution worked as expected when tested with an example. Thank you for your assistance and support.

Comment: can you recommend me a tutorial to understand complex regex operators like ?: and ?<!

Comment: @OmarFareed See [What is a non-capturing group in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/3832970) and [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/3832970). Besides, see https://regular-expressions.info and https://rexegg.com/.